# Reduce the nested loops and improve readability in Java

Tags: java, loops, sonarqube

I am working on a java application. Sonar is complaining about the nested loops for having more than 3 nested loops.

Code:

```
if(someCondition){
  List<Integer> list = getIds();

  if(list != null){
     for(int id : list){
         String str1 = someObject.getStr();
         String str2 = someObject.getString();
         if (StringUtils.isBlank(str1)) {
             str1 = NA;
          }
          if (StringUtils.isBlank(str2)) {
              str2 = NA;
           }
        // something else
     }
  }

}
```

Sonar Error:

```
Refactor this code to not nest more than 3 if/for/while/switch/try statements.
```

How can I resolve that issue? I can't think of any other idea than keeping it in a separate method which is adding unnecessary extra steps and increases the lines of code as well. Is there any other alternative for this issue?

Comment: Given that your code is already running, and you just want to improve upon it, your question might be better suited to our sister site, [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: There is no such thing as a `List<int>`; your example needs a little more context.

Comment: You could use the Ternary operator "condition?Yes:No". Although, keeping separate functions is a good way of increasing the readability and cleaning the code. This also solve Sonar warning. In fact Uncle Bob's Clean Code recommends this way of writing code.

Comment: You iterate over the ids but do not use the id variable. This seems like some random code.

Comment: @gagansingh i just gave a blueprint of the exact issue i am facing. But i think i am clear with my question?

Comment: You can create a method which can have this condition `StringUtils.isBlank(str1)`. You can pass `omeObject.getStr()` to it. If string is empty, it should return `NA` else return the string

Comment: Honestly, that code looks perfectly fine to me, so unless you're required to change it for some reason, I'd just leave it alone.

Comment: @Radiodef Sonar is complaining about the maintainability and readability . So that needs to be fixed for me :(

Comment: i think tools warn us about `potential` issues, its us who have to decide if its an actual issue and if so we must fix it. But if its intentional and you know why you have that code and its not an issue then its ok to accept the code and move ahead with it.

Comment: 'Sonar is complaining about the nested loops for having more than 3 nested loops.' No it isn't . Read the message.

Comment: @EJP, you seem to nitpick the words and dismiss the question. The author doesn't want to have warnings, complaints, remarks and the like. He has the right and there is a way. Your attitude is unconstructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code is not nested **loops** more than 3, is more than 3 nested **if**.
Maybe you can improve your getIds() method that never returns null, that's for some reason method should not return null. If is should be null,Then you could use return or break to end the program like :

```
if(list == null)
  return;
```

Finally, you can try ternary operator to make sure the values of str1 and str2.

```
  String str1 = StringUtils.isBlank(someObject.getStr()) ? NA : someObject.getStr();
  String str2 = StringUtils.isBlank(someObject.getString()) ? NA : someObject.getString();
```

Comment: this helped a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
boolean someConditionIsTrue;
List<Integer> list;

if(someCondition){
    someConditionIsTrue = true;
    list = getIds();
}

if(list != null && someConditionIsTrue){
    for(int id : list){
        String str1 = someObject.getStr();
        String str2 = someObject.getString();
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(str1)) {
            str1 = NA;
        }
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(str2)) {
            str2 = NA;
        }
        //something else
    }
}
```

However, it's not that elegant.

Answer (score -1):

Just a bit of simplification:

```
    List<Integer> list;
    // Declare the list outside if-condition

    if (someCondition && (list = getIds()) != null) {
    //                   ================   assign it to getId() right inside the condition check

        for (int id : list) {

            // declare same type variables via a comma
            String 
                str1 = obj.getStr(),  
                str2 = obj.getString();

            // get rid of unobligatory {} brackets
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(str1)) str1 = NA;
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(str2)) str2 = NA;

            //something else
        }
    }
```